# Building Game Physics Engine: 2D rectangle normals - juxtaposition of picture and equation

Tags: javascript, vector, graphics, 2d, normals

Once again I go back to learning graphics from scratch (as many of the others when I was kid, I wanted to build games and stuff, but currenlty I am generic monkey-coder, but anyway).

Started to read this simple book ([Building a 2D Game Physics Engine: Using HTML5 and JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484225821)), and when it came to rectangle normals there were the picture and the equations related to it.

Here is the picture:

[image]

Here is the code, pretty striaghtforward, from the book (`Vec2` is simple lib of functions which make simple vector operations)

```
function RigidShape(center) {
 this.mCenter = center;
 this.mAngle = 0;
 gEngine.Core.mAllObjects.push(this);
}

var Rectangle = function(center, width,height){
    RigidShape.call(this, center);

    this.mType = "Rectangle";
    this.mWidth = width;
    this.mHeight = height;
    this.mVertex =[];
    this.mFaceNormal = [];

    //0--TopLeft;1--TopRight;2--BottomRight;3--BottomLeft
    this.mVertex[0] = new Vec2(center.x - width / 2, center.y -
    height / 2);
    this.mVertex[1] = new Vec2(center.x + width / 2, center.y -
    height / 2);
    this.mVertex[2] = new Vec2(center.x + width / 2, center.y +
    height / 2);
    this.mVertex[3] = new Vec2(center.x - width / 2, center.y +
    height / 2);

    //0--Top;1--Right;2--Bottom;3--Left
    //mFaceNormal is normal of face toward outside of rectangle
    this.mFaceNormal[0] = this.mVertex[1].subtract(this.mVertex[2]);
    this.mFaceNormal[0] = this.mFaceNormal[0].normalize();
    this.mFaceNormal[1] = this.mVertex[2].subtract(this.mVertex[3]);
    this.mFaceNormal[1] = this.mFaceNormal[1].normalize();
    this.mFaceNormal[2] = this.mVertex[3].subtract(this.mVertex[0]);
    this.mFaceNormal[2] = this.mFaceNormal[2].normalize();
    this.mFaceNormal[3] = this.mVertex[0].subtract(this.mVertex[1]);
    this.mFaceNormal[3] = this.mFaceNormal[3].normalize();

    var prototype = Object.create(RigidShape.prototype);
    prototype.constructor = Rectangle;
    Rectangle.prototype = prototype;
};
```

I was studying CS in university, including some linear algebra so I still rembemer that `normal` is the vector, perpendicular to surface it applied.
And the picture is fine.

But, when I try to make calculations due to whats in code I got the other picture in my mind(paper).

Here is what my mind drawns
[image]

**The problem is that I can't see that the code from the book and the picture from the book are represents the same as it should be!**

Is here is something wrong or did I missed something?

**UPD normalize function**

```
var Vec2 = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

Vec2.prototype.length = function () {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
};

Vec2.prototype.normalize = function () {

    var len = this.length();
    if (len > 0) {
        len = 1 / len;
    }
    return new Vec2(this.x * len, this.y * len);
};
```

Comment: not sure what you did in your mind but if I look at the code I would obtain the same thing. So my bet is you got bug in the substract method which results in perpendicular vector.   if you want perpendicular vector in 2D to any vector just swap coordinates and negate one so `(x,y)`  is perpendicular to `(-y,x)` and `(y,-x)` so you should apply this after the real substraction.

Comment: @Spektre I added the picture thou with colored normal vector arrows ._.

Comment: @Spektre I ubderstand how I can get perpendicular. The problem is - picture in book and the one I got accoridng to what described in code are different

Comment: @Spektre AFAIK I draw the substraction in a proper way https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/VectorSubtract.png

Comment: You wrote that the code generates correct image in that case `subtract` or `normalize` must swap coordinates and negate one. Last option I can think of is you draw them rotated

Comment: @Spektre no, no, code doesnt draw anything, it just calculate specific rectange characteristics (sorry, my english is bad, maybe I used wrong expressions).
The first picture it's from book and it should represent vectors and vertexes of the created object. Second one - mine calcs.

Comment: in that case you still missing the rotation by 90 degree. For that swap the coordinates and negate one. In 3D and more use cross product ...

Comment: @Spektre that code is also from book, and it use `normalize` function, which just normalize vector, i''ll update the question

Answer (score 0):

in the book , the author explained why?
"Face normal index-0 is in the same direction as the vector from
vertex 2 to 1."